# TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) discord bot error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, typeerror

I need help in this error because I couldn't find anything on the internet here's the code

```
class MyClient(discord.client):
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged in as')
    print(self.user.name)
    print(self.user.id)
    print('------')
```

I have discord imported and I don't know how to fix it so I would be glad if anyone helped me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`discord.client` is a module (a file), you're looking for the class which starts with capital letter

```py
class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as')
        print(self.user.name)
        print(self.user.id)
        print('------')
```

Comment: @zukakuprashvili If it worked then you should accept his answer